# Delete operation via lambda functions

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
  let calcium = Set([
        ":calcium"
    ])
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your AWS)
        let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.defaultLambdaInvoker()
        let jsonObject: [String: AnyObject] = [
            "TableName":  "diaFitMessages",
            "operation": "update" ,
            //import email from other view controller -> public variable
            "Key": ["email": email],
            "UpdateExpression": "delete #date :responses",
            "ExpressionAttributeNames": [
                "#date": currentDate
            ],
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": [
                ":responses": calcium
            ],
            "ReturnValues": "NONE"
        ]
        let task = lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("handlerDiaFIT", JSONObject: jsonObject)
        task.continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in
            if task.error != nil {
                print(task.error)


            } else {
                print("DELETED")]
```

For some reason I keep getting *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_TtGCs22_NativeSetStorageOwnerSS_)'
even though my currentDate is a correct string and my responses is a set.

Comment: `Set` cannot be converted to JSON data

Comment: Ok so do you have any idea how to delete a column from Dynamo DB via this lambda function? Like I have the column attribute name. That "key" is the currentDate

Comment: Just use Array instead of Set